# Roubler API query syntax

Tags: powerquery

I have been able to successfully retrieve data from the Roubler API (using a PowerQuery) but I am having trouble modifying the initial queries they have provided.  For example the Timesheet Query that is working is:

```
 let
   apiUrl = "https://app.roubler.com.au",
   accessToken = "MyToken",
       body = [
      operationName = "Timesheets",
    variables = [
    startTime = "2023-05-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    endTime = "2023-07-27T23:59:59.999Z",
    locationId = "13216"
    ],

query = "query Timesheets($startTime: DateTime!, $endTime: DateTime!, $locationId: ID!) { timesheets(startTime: $startTime, endTime: $endTime, locationId: $locationId, strictRange: true) { id cost variance startTime endTime hours status breaks { id startTime endTime subtracts } location { id name timezone rosterable } employee { id fullName } modifiedAt statusModifiedAt }}"
    ],
    requestBody = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(body)),
    headers = [
        #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
        #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & accessToken
    ],
    options = [
        Headers = headers,
        ManualStatusHandling = {404}, // Modify as needed based on expected response codes
        Content = Text.ToBinary(requestBody),
        RelativePath="/graphql"
    ],
    apiResponse = Web.Contents(apiUrl, options),
    jsonResponse = Json.Document(apiResponse),
    data = jsonResponse[data],
    timesheets = data[timesheets],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(timesheets, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

However I want to add in more information like PayRun, PayLevel, PayType, CostCentre etc but I am not able to form the syntax correctly.  Here is the reference from Roubler:
https://docs.roubler.com/page/reference#query

Any help adding these in would be much appreciated!